# SASS: How to ignore a loop

Tags: css, arrays, sass

I have two SCSS arrays (`$color_options` and `$object_options`).

I want to use SCSS to loop through both arrays to combine values from both of them.

I have created a function to do this and everything works fine. However, there are times when I want to only to loop through the colour array and ignore the object array. How can I do this?

Here is my code(*):

```
@function generic-avatar-hidden($color_options: $color_options, $object_options: $object_options) {
    $bg: compact();

    @each $ov in $object_options {
        $o-css-selector: nth($ov, 1);

        @each $cv in $color_options {
            $c-css-selector: nth($cv, 1);
            $assetname: $o-css-selector + $c-css-selector;

            $bg: join($bg, image-url("#{$root-directory}/#{$brand}/#{$product}/#{$type}/#{$product}-#{$type}-#{$path-pre}#{$assetname}#{$path-post}.#{$ext}"), comma);
        }
        // Close CV
    }
    // Close OV
    @return $bg;
}
```

---

**Steps I have taken:**

I have tried wrapping all the code to do with the object_options in `@if $object_options != null`. 
This works, but when `$object_options` is supposed to be use, the function will only loop through the last item in the `$object_options` array.

---

**Code Examples**

(*) This is a cut down version of my code. The full examples can be found here:

[Full version](http://codepen.io/madhusharma/pen/cahol?editors=011) which doesn't use `@if $object_options != null`

[Updated version](http://codepen.io/madhusharma/pen/HIbcA) with `@if $object_options != null`

**Expected Output **
(This is based on the full version of the code linked above)

http://pastebin.com/gVykec8X

Basically, $color_options & $object_options all have 5 elements inside of them. 
The SCSS code takes elements from $color_options and $object_options and combines them. However, if $object_options is set to null, then there will be no combination and only elements from $color_options will be used.

Comment: Can you show the output you're expecting?

Comment: There is no other way but wrapping code in `@if`s https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/378

Comment: @JAre Please could you post your comment as answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[sass doesn't support break or continue statements](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/378). You should use `@if` to implement branching.

Comment: lead developer of sass thinks that this isn't fundamental to loops because it's not a "full fledged programming language". Which is ridiculous imo.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, a `@return` can often be as good as a `break` if you don't mind giving the loop its own function